# PHP Printer How to use printer_draw_text Function

Tags: php, printing, epson

Sorry For my BAD English

My Question is, how can I use `printer_draw_text` Function to print out a long String? (See example) on an **Epson Billing Printer**.

All The examples work (source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php)

But when I want to combine a Logo.bmp + a long line of text it will only print out the logo and 1 line of sting:

**Example:**

```
<?php

# DEMO PRINTER

//http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-write.php
/*
$_SESSION['PrintBuffer']='';         //printer buffer
  print_sub_1();
  print_sub_2();
  print_sub_3();

  $_SESSION['PrintBuffer']

*/

$Printer_name = $_GET['Printer'];
$text = $_GET['value'];

$text = str_replace( '/r/n',PHP_EOL, $text);

$handle = printer_open($Printer_name);  // Open Pritner by Name
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
//printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_LEFT);

printer_start_doc($handle, "Print"); // Name Document 

printer_start_page($handle); // Start Logo
printer_draw_bmp($handle, "c:\\logo.bmp", 60, 0);  // Logo Dir, lenght H , With V
printer_end_page($handle);  // End Logo

printer_start_page($handle);    
printer_draw_text($handle, $text,1,1);
printer_end_page($handle);  //

printer_end_doc($handle);   // Close document 
printer_close($handle);     // Close Pritner

?>
```

**Output Example:**

Logo.bmp

Test.... // But only 1 line :(

The printer_write($handle, "Text to print"); Works !!! it prints out hole String + the \r\n But It prints out the logo on a new paper :(

Needed example

Logo  <-- here

1 x product <-- Long String 1 x product \r\n ( working printer_write function )
 2 x product 
ecr.

`printer_draw_text($handle, $text,1,1);` is printing out only 1 x product 2 x

Comment: Does it work if you use `printer_write` and remove the `printer_end_page` `printer_start_page` between the logo and text?

Comment: Hi Chris thnx for you comment. No it will not work for me it will still print out 2 tickets... But I found how to do it see below

Comment: I Use a string to Array function $lineofText = explode(',',$text); and than make a for loop to make new printer_draw_text functoin

Comment: Cool, put the final code in as an Answer with that explanation.

Comment: @Chris i know this is really old but do you know why when i use more than 1 `printer_draw_text` on the same page it only outputs the last one?

Comment: @TerisL Sorry I don't know, it's been a long time.  The only thing I can think of at the moment (and I may be way off here) is if the print functions work anything like other output, then maybe something with output buffering needs to be looked at.

Comment: No problem, i found the extension to be buggy as hell. When you get the printer list it'll crash whenever you try to get `DESCRIPTION` or `COMMENTS` part of it's printer array.

Answer (score 1):

Here by working example
(* + Print.Dll and on a Win 7 OS )

```
  <?php

# DEMO PRINTER

//http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-write.php
/*
$_SESSION['PrintBuffer']='';         //printer buffer
  print_sub_1();
  print_sub_2();
  print_sub_3();

  $_SESSION['PrintBuffer']

*/

$Printer_name = $_GET['Printer'];
$text = $_GET['value'];

$text = str_replace( "-"," ", $text);
$text = str_replace( "/r/n"," \r\n , ", $text); // replace and make string Array

$lineofText = explode(',',$text); // Array to stand to for


# Examples 

// testing font
//echo printer_logical_fontheight($printer, 72);

//printer_set_option($printer, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");



$handle = printer_open($Printer_name);  // Open Pritner by Name
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
//printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_LEFT);


printer_start_doc($handle, " Print"); // Name Document 


printer_start_page($handle); // Start Logo
printer_draw_bmp($handle, "c:\\logo.bmp", 60, 0);  // Logo Dir, lenght H , With V
printer_end_page($handle);  // End Logo

printer_start_page($handle);    // Text

$asize=sizeof($lineofText);             // Make NewLine per Array 
   for($i=0; $i<$asize; $i++)    {
                                    printer_draw_text($handle, $lineofText[$i],1,1);
                                }

printer_end_page($handle);  // End Text

//printer_start_page($handle); // Start Logo QR
//printer_draw_bmp($handle, "c:\\QR.bmp", 60, 0);  // Logo Dir, lenght H , With V
//printer_end_page($handle);  // End Logo QR

printer_end_doc($handle);   // Close document 
printer_close($handle);     // Close Pritner


?>
```